# Proving $2^{2^n} \equiv 1(\mod 5)$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

> Prove that $2^{2^n} \equiv 1(\mod 5)$, when $n>1$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you keep squaring the number two, you get the sequence [2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, etc.](http://oeis.org/A001146) in which the general term is $2^{2^n}$. Now if you keep squaring the number two **modulo 5**, you get the sequence $2, 4, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$. See the implications? As soon as you have squared more than once, you keep getting $1$.

Comment: By the way, a prime $p$ with the property that the sequence $ 2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, \ldots$ taken modulo $p$ eventually becomes $\ldots, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$, is a [divisor of a Fermat number](http://oeis.org/A023394).

Comment: Square a number which ends in a $6$ and you get a $6$ at the end ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2^2=4\equiv-1\pmod5\implies (2^2)^m\equiv\begin{cases}1 &\mbox{if } m\text{ is even} \\ -1 & \mbox{if } m \text{ is odd} \end{cases} $$

So here, we need  $2^n$ to be divisible by $2\cdot2=2^2$ which is true if $?$

---

Alternatively, $\displaystyle 2^{2^n}=(2^2)^{2^{n-1}}\equiv(-1)^{2^{n-1}}\pmod5$

So, we need $\displaystyle2^{n-1}$ to be even $\iff$ integer $n-1>0$